# What are the integrals of these simple derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to integrate an equation from a journal article to understand what it was derived from. However, it has been 20 years since I learned the basics of integration in high school and I am hazy on the memory.

I have the following terms:

$\frac{3}{2}EA(y_x)^2y_{xx} + 2γAy_xy_{xt}y_{xx} + γA(y_x)^2y_{xxt}$

$γ$, $E$, and $A$ are constants. Subscripts are derivatives of $x$ and time.

I am trying to figure out the integral of these terms with respect to $x$. In other words, I want to know what these terms were before they were derived once by $x$. Or expressed simply:

$[N]_x = \frac{3}{2}EA(y_x)^2y_{xx} + 2γAy_xy_{xt}y_{xx} + γA(y_x)^2y_{xxt}$

What is $N$ in this condition?

I've been staring at integration rules but I'm not really sure how to use them. I hope if this is pretty easy for someone with more math experience someone can help me out. It would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $N=\frac12 EA y_x^3+\gamma A y_x^2 y_{xt}$ should do it.

Comment: Thanks semiclassical! I'm looking at your solution and trying to understand how that works. I must have been doing my derivations wrong. You're saying $[\frac{1}{2}EAy_x^3]_x = \frac{3}{2}EA(y_x)^2y_{xx}$ then, right? But I don't follow that. How is that done? I think you follow exponent rule first which makes $[\frac{1}{2}EAy_x^3]_x = [\frac{3}{2}EAy_x^2$ but then where does the $y_{xx}$ come from? What's the basic rule or principle that creates this? I think that's my error I'm making all over so if I can understand that I'll be good for everything. Thanks again.

Comment: First, one way to see that an error has occurred is to consider the case $[y_x]_x$. If you think of that as $(y_x)^1$, then your logic would give that as $[y_x]_x=1$. But it should be $[y_x]_x=y_{xx}$. What you're forgetting is the chain rule: If $f,z$ are functions of $x$, then the derivative of $f(z(x))$ is $f'(z(x))z'(x)$. So $[f(y_x)]_x = f_x(y_x)y_{xx}$.

Comment: Okay so the exponent rule only applies for constants. Functions with exponents must be dealt with via the chain rule. Got it. I know that your solution implies $(y_x^3)_x = 3y_x^2y_{xx}$. I tried following the chain rule as: $(fg)'=(f'g)g'$ by rewording it as $(y_xy_x^2)_x$. Then you get from the chain rule $(y_{xx}y_x^2)(y_x^2)_x$. Applying the chain rule again to the second piece gives a final equation of  $(y_{xx}y_x^2)(y_{xx}y_x)y_{xx} = y_{xx}^3y_x^3$. But obviously this is wrong too so I'm now screwing up the chain rule. Argh. Any further direction to help me understand? :) Thanks again.

Comment: You're conflating the chain rule and the product rule. The chain rule applies to compositions of functions, e.g., $y_x^3=f(y_x)$ where $f(x)=x^3$. For products of functions, we have $(fg)'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$. So $$[y_x y_x^2]_x=[y_x]_x y_x^2+y_x[y_x^2]_x=y_{xx}y_x^2+y_x (2y_x y_{xx})=3y_{xx}y_x^2$$ in agreement with the chain rule.

Comment: Okay. I get it. Thanks very much.